# exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de python junto con TypeScript, al momento de realizar el compilado se me genera mi archivo `.js` pero al momento que entro a la pagina web en la consola me sale el error

```
exports is not defined
```

Este archivo se llama `video.ts` y termina renderizado así

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var controls_video_1 = require("./class/controls_video");
window.onload = init;
var video;
var shortcut, player;
function init() {
    video = document.getElementById("video");
    player = new controls_video_1.Controls_video(video);
    shortcut.add("space", player.reproducir);
    shortcut.add("right", player.adelantar_5);
    shortcut.add("left", player.retroceder_5);
    shortcut.add("f", player.full_screen);
    init_listeners();
}
function init_listeners() {
    var volume = document.getElementById("volumen");
    var playStop = document.getElementById("playStop");
    volume.addEventListener("change", player.set_volume);
    playStop.addEventListener("click", player.reproducir);
}
```

El error me lo marca en la línea 2 `exports.__esModule = true;`.
Mi versión de TypeScript es `4.4.4` y la versión de EcmaScript con la que se renderiza a JS es `ES5`

Acabo de generar el archivo `tsconfig.json` con el comando `tsc --init` y el contenido es esto (quitando las lineas comentadas):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es5",                                     /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu archivo **tsconfig.json** para ver si por allí va el problema

Comment: @SaulEspinoza listo, lo he agregado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una variable de los módulos de *Node.js*, hay que quitarla.

También va a dar problemas el `require`, al parecer se está compilando mal, o para Node.

```
require("./class/controls_video");
```

Se podría mirar en la configuración de la compilación y cambiar las opciones... Otra manera es agregar el archivo `.js`, pero si es *TypeScript* entonces no se puede.

```
var s = document.createElement("script")
s.src = "./class/controls_video/index.js"
document.head.appendChild(s)
```

---

### Alternativa

Hay que crear el archivo **tsconfig.browser.json** y asignar la siguiente opción.

```
"outDir": "./dist.browser",
```

Luego ejecutar el siguiente comando, o agregarlo en `package.json`:

```
tsc -p tsconfig.browser.json
```

La estructura del archivo **tsconfig.browser.json** es parecida a la del **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist.browser",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom", "es5"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Fuente: https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/typescript-create-library-for-nodejs-and-browser-fece291d517f

Se podría incluso copiar la configuración del otro archivo y cambiarle los parámetros.

Si sigues teniendo problemas puede ser por que al parecer no todos los navegadores tienen soporte para `import`... Veo una respuesta en SO en inglés, agregan `type="module"` al script de esta manera

```
<script src="t1.js" type="module"></script>
```

y funciona desde Firefox 60... Si es posible, es mejor evitar el `import`

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624819/es2015-import-doesnt-work-even-at-top-level-in-firefox

Comment: Por si sirve de algo, he agregado el `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Me pordrías decir como crear el archivo `tsconfig.browser.json` y cual sería su estructura por favor? Por otra parte, no sé si influye pero... no he creado un proyecto de node (no he ejecutado `npm init`) por que mi proyecto de es de python y solo trabajo con typescript para el frontend

Comment: @Christian Edité la respuesta... Parece que de manera predeterminada se compila para Node, si no se puede con `tsc`, puede usarse una librería externa como webpack. Quizás lo resuelva el parámetro `-p`, aunque no estoy seguro.

Comment: al ejecutar el comando `tsc -p tsconfig.browser.json` me ha marcado varios errores de funciones duplicadas de mis archivos typescript :(

Comment: @Christian ¿Son muchas las duplicadas? Habría que dejarlas comentadas las que estén duplicadas, puede ser que varios submódulos requieren el mismo módulo y por eso hay duplicadas.

Comment: ya he "solucionado" los errores de duplicado y he ejecuado el comando y no he notado ningún cambio :(

Comment: quitando el `outDir` ya me aparecen los archivos. Peroo.. al momento de ingresar a la web me aparece `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Comment: @Christian Busqué y al parecer no todos los navegadores tienen soporte para `import`... Veo una respuesta en SO en inglés, agregan `type="module"` al `script` de esta manera `<script src="t1.js" type="module"></script>` y funciona desde Firefox 60... Si es posible, es mejor evitar el `import`... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624819/es2015-import-doesnt-work-even-at-top-level-in-firefox

Comment: lo siento molestarte tanto, pero en mi ejemplo como sería? No logro conseguir que funcione bien

Comment: @Christian Me imagino que es algo así... `var s = document.createElement("script"); s.src = "./class/controls_video/index.js"; s.type = "module"; document.head.appendChild(s)`, hay que buscar el archivo js que esté en esa carpeta. Luego importar la función... `import foo from 'index.js';`

Comment: muchas gracias, no aceptaré la respuesta por ahora para ver si alguien más responde. En unos días acepto tu respuesta si no hay otra